# registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution() method call

Tags: swift, branch.io, skadnetwork

Im using Branch SDK to supports SKAdNetwork.
https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/branchskadnetwork-integration-instructions#app-option-1-use-the-branch-sdk-to-manage-skadnetwork
I added StoreKit to my iOS app, in the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skadnetwork/2943654-registerappforadnetworkattributi they mention that this function is been called after the first launch of an app installed as a result of an ad.
but I didn't find any documentation that talks about where and how to implement it, is it on the app side or on the Branch side. How do I know that its been triggered? how to call it? should I import something?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are using Branch SDK with option to let SDK manage SKAdNetwork. If that’s the case, once you initialise SDK in App e.g. in didFinishLaunch function, SDK will take care of registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution Call. You don’t need to call it again in App.
If you opt to manage SKAdNetwork yourself, then you need to call registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution From within App didFinishLaunch function. Ideally call it only once per app install, though Apple documentation says there is not effect if you call it multiple times.

Comment: yes that's right, I'm using the Branch SDK with option to let SDK manage SKAdNetwork, but I'm not finding a way to call the registerAppForAdNetworKAttribute() , should we import something? how can I be sure that its been triggered?

Comment: Again, you don't need to call or worry about calling registerAppForAdNetworkAttribution if you are letting Branch SDK to manage it for you. Just make sure you are initialising Branch SDK on App launch. To verify if Branch SDK is doing its job, you need to 1) Get a Test profile for SKAdNetwork (https://help.branch.io/faq/docs/i-updated-my-app-for-skadnetwork-but-i-do-not-see-my-test-data-in-the-branch-dashboard) and then use Charles proxy to look for a post back to branch (https://help.branch.io/using-branch/docs/test-skadnetwork-integration).